# Names of axis when drawing vectors in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors

In his [MIT 18.06](https://youtu.be/ZK3O402wf1c?t=580) course, when presenting the "column" view of linear algebra, Strang draws vectors as shown below:

[image]

I am assuming that the axis shown on the blackboard (which I have highlighted) are not $x$ and $y$, but an arbitrary system for depicting vectors.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: the horizontal axis represents the first coordinate and the vertical axis the second, so the vector depicted on the board is $\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\end{bmatrix}$, the first vector in the equation to the left of the graph in the image. This is akin to the Argand diagram for complex numbers.